# Sharing internet without wifi

Tags: networking, ethernet, lan, switch

How can I use the Internet on two computers when I only have one Ethernet cable connected to the switch in my hostels's server room which is further connected to central sever room which is further connected to NIC optical fiber cable Network? I cannot use WiFi because my IBM Thinkpad laptop does not have wireless.

My college network (LAN + Internet) has a proxy server and routers in a central server room then switches in each hostel. The Ethernet cable is coming from one of those switches.

I have tried LAN splitter but it did not work.

Comment: There's not enough information here for us to answer you.  Try a switch, if it doesn't work, get a router. As-is, you're not showing any research effort for something that is a pretty basic question. Perhaps check these out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_(computing) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch

Comment: Can you plz tell me What info is needed.

Comment: You would have to ask a network administrator. There's no way we can know. You could get a cheap WiFi router, set it up as a switch, see if it works, and if it doesn't, set it up as a router. (You can disable the WiFi if you don't want it.)

Comment: Is WiFi not an option because there is no WiFi broadcast or only because the Thinkpad lacks WiFi?  If it's the latter, you can get an inexpensive WiFi USB dongle for the Thinkpad.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 If I wanted to trying switch than router than I haven't asked this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like from that description that you need a switch which would be plugged into the patch port in your room and then plugged into both computers. An alternative would be to get WiFi but on the Thinkpad you could either get a USB WiFi adapter or create a bridged connection between the two computers.
Hope this helped